# Disable the Security Essentials End-of-Life Warning on Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, ms-security-essentials

Is it possible to disable the "Support for this operating system is ending" warning that the current version of Microsoft Security Essentials displays on Windows XP?

[image: Support ending notification]

Based on a quick couple of searches, this warning appears to have been added in the KB2949787 update to Security Essentials, but I can't see a way to revert just that update.

**Aside**: Since I'm sure people are going to ask, here is why I want to do this:

- I already have a plan to migrate soon
- The warning is nagging other people who can't do anything about it
- Since the warning state uses the orange warning icon and popups, it makes real anti-virus warnings that people may need to know about harder to notice (Edit: Actually, the orange icon and popup is typically only used for less serious conditions like out of date definitions and lack of a recent quick scan, not 'real anti-virus warnings' as such.)

Comment: There is no way to disable this warning.  The actual notification alert that is separate from this can be disabled.

Comment: I should clarify my comment.  There is no way to disable this warning and have the update installed.

Comment: Uninstall MSE and install something else?

Comment: @joeqwerty Feel free to post that as an answer, because that might be the best one. =)

Comment: +1 This is annoying my parents at the moment which is frustrating as they want to keep the operating system they are familiar with and MSE. But the nag screen is concerning them.

Comment: @brettdj it is doing its job then.

Comment: @Mr.Mindor from a purist sense yes. But given my parents wont be updating their machine, are light users of the net mainly of newspaper sites and for flight bookings, and they are in a low risk category and what they have works for them

Comment: @brettdj How do they book flights? With a credit card? Ah... Right, on a Operating System without security updates. That's sounds... interesting.

Comment: @M.Mimpen managing bookings and arrival times yes. using credit cards no - as I said low risk. I'm sure though you still think they should live in total terror.

Comment: @brettdj I assumed you implied that they 'book flights' - which often uses a credit card. Besides that, I do think they should update, yes.

Comment: THats how windows makes money- making their users annoyed. Updates are never needed. Updatss slow computer and without them you need only antivirus. Very rarely some computer experts need updates. I have never had any virus solved with update but only problems with updates.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

## Workaround

The end-of-support pop-up notification can't be disabled, and downgrading isn't really an option: Microsoft Security Essentials (MSE) would upgrade itself again, sooner or later. While you could still try to prevent it from upgrading, there's no guarantee that the old MSE version would still receive updates as usual.

Considering the notification is generated by the user interface executable, you can override it with an earlier version while keeping the up-to-date engine.

#### Update (May 30, 2014)

As commented by @saulius2, the registry changes were detected as a tampering threat. My previous method has been abused by malware creators for malicious purposes, and that's why MSE complained about it. To solve this issue I've since switched to a different approach. In case you applied this workaround before, just follow steps 6-7 again.

Eventually you will need to switch to a [different antivirus](http://www.av-comparatives.org/) solution, as the MSE definition signatures won't be updated anymore on Windows XP after July 14, 2015. For the time being, however, the steps below should do the trick:

1. Get a copy of version `4.4.304.0` of the MSE installer. Any language will do, see the file information below.
2. Log on with an administrator account, and extract the `mseinstall.exe` file using [7-Zip](http://www.7-zip.org/).
3. Open the `x86` folder, and extract `epp.msi` though 7-Zip.
4. Rename the extracted `msseces.exe` file to `msseces2.exe`.
5. Copy `msseces2.exe` to the MSE install folder (e.g. `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Security Client`).
6. Open a command prompt, type or paste the following command, and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>:

   ```
   reg add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run" /v "MSC" /t REG_SZ /d "\"%programfiles%\Microsoft Security Client\msseces2.exe\" -hide -runkey" /f
   ```
7. Restart Windows.

**Note** Although unlikely, make sure to repeat steps 6-7 should MSE upgrade in the future.

### Screenshots

#### Before

Until April 8, 2014:

[image: MSE screenshot 1]
[image: MSE screenshot 3]
[image: MSE screenshot 4]

April 8, 2014 onwards:

[image: MSE screenshot 5]
[image: MSE screenshot 6]
[image: MSE screenshot 7]

#### After

[image: MSE screenshot 8]
[image: MSE screenshot 10]

*Click for larger view.*

---

## Additional information

> [Microsoft Security Essentials](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security-essentials-download) will not be available for download on Windows XP after April 8, 2014. If you already have Microsoft Security Essentials installed, you will continue to receive anti-malware signature updates through July 14, 2015.
>
> <sub>Source: [Support for Windows XP for Enterprise Business is ending](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/enterprise/end-of-support.aspx)</sub>

### Version updgrade

> Version `4.5.216.0` of [Microsoft Security Essentials](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security-essentials-download) was deployed on the 26th of March, 2014. On Windows XP, the status displayed permanently became Amber/Yellow indicating "Potentially Unprotected."
>
> After the 8th of April, the date support for Windows XP ended, the status became Red indicating "At Risk."
>
> This is by design due to the fact that [Windows XP end of support is 8 April, 2014](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/enterprise/end-of-support.aspx).
>
> - You cannot change the status of Microsoft Security Essentials to Green on Windows XP after the upgrade.
> - The notification tray icon for Microsoft Security Essentials will remain Red or Amber/Yellow if no other issues are detected.
> - You cannot uninstall the upgrade and return to the prior version as it will automatically upgrade.
>
> <sub>Source: [Microsoft Security Essentials 4.5.216.0 on Windows XP - At Risk > 9 April, 2014](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/protect/wiki/mse-protect_start/microsoft-security-essentials-452160-on-windows-xp/1328d67a-5720-4481-8662-e52a49a11a22)</sub>

### File information

As Microsoft no longer provides MSE for download on Windows XP, you need to rely on third parties who can provide the old setup package. Here are the basic details and hashes of the official US English (`en-US`) installer and the user interface executable (which is language neutral):

```
File:    mseinstall.exe
Size:    10.6 MiB (11125072 bytes)
Version: 4.4.304.0
---
CRC32:   26db621c
MD5:     f406bac9cfb876eff01314f18cda746c
SHA1:    6ea36a8b108517a4dc692afc30aad122af543239
SHA256:  6b5846385cd3bd3e7b9ddb2f8667c2f927ff17c47d6891b526895614539dbd02

File:    msseces.exe
Size:    926.2 KiB (948440 bytes)
Version: 4.4.304.0
---
CRC32:   8fb6f338
MD5:     03396637e1e1b4e333d00aed86178918
SHA1:    59203d5d1c5d78e30f0c3d0e9b364f37a2558cf8
SHA256:  cf582487e856d01c960392ac658e8d36a92f2b2b4b9aea9bfc9e6f75fbad6571
```

While different languages have different setup packages (hence different details), all of them include identical copies of the `msseces.exe` file, which has to be digitally signed by `Microsoft Corporation`, and countersigned by `Microsoft Time-Stamp Service`; both signatures must be valid. You can check them by opening the file properties dialog.

### Download links

You can use any of these, or find an alternate source yourself. While the actual file name could be different, the other **details provided above must match exactly**.

Make sure to scan the files using your antivirus, and upload a copy to [VirusTotal](https://www.virustotal.com/) to feel confident enough. If possible, test the program in a safe environment first. When you're done, make a backup of the executable.

- http://www.filehippo.com/download_security_essentials_xp/51102
- http://www.filehorse.com/download-security-essentials-xp/15350/
- http://www.filesoul.com/software/Microsoft-Security-Essentials-XP/Security-Essentials-4-4-304-XP/
- http://orbitaldownloads.com/security-essentials-xp_4.4.304/
- http://www.fruitydownload.com/download/security-essentials-4-4-304-xp.html
- http://www.mediafire.com/download/00xkln4kaxo6t4h/MSEInstall.exe
- http://bin.ge/dl/90509/mseinstall.exe.html
- http://ulub.pl/1zYDbfBkQe/microsoft-security-essentials-xp-44304
- http://youshare.ge/?d=528326415
- http://youshare.ge/?d=532E394E5

### End-of-life status

> [MSE] also provides a registry [value] to show the current end-of-life status of the current OS if it’s near end-of-life. [It's called] `EndOfLifeState` [and is stored in] `HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Microsoft Antimalware`.
>
> **Stage 1: OS is approaching end-of-life.** At this stage, the OS is near the end of its support lifecycle. [MSE] will still work as normal.
>
> **Stage 2: Grace period.** OS has reached end-of-life, but anti-malware platform service is still running and definition updates can be received. For example, for Windows XP, the Grace Period stage starts on April 8, 2014.
>
> **Stage 3: Anti-malware service stopped.** You can no longer start the anti-malware service, and your computer will not receive anti-malware definition updates. Thus [MSE] will no longer help to protect your computer. For example, for Windows XP, this stage starts on July 14th, 2015.
>
> <sub>Source: [FEP and SCEP anti-malware protection support after OSes reach end-of-life](http://blogs.technet.com/b/configmgrteam/archive/2014/03/27/fep-and-scep-anti-malware-protection-support-after-oses-reach-end-of-life.aspx)</sub>

Despite what the official source says, the third stage may happen sooner than expected: as the commenter KY noted, the anti-malware service will stop as early as June 15, 2015. Whether intentional or not, this was confirmed by my tests as well.

Comment: `Stage 3: Anti-malware service stopped. You can no longer start the anti-malware service` But they specifically said that things would continue to work, just not be updated and thus, potentially vulnerable. By *blocking* it from running it, they are countering what they promised. Their excuse is probably something like “the defs will be outdated, so letting users continue to run it would give them a false sense of security” or some BS like that. That’s BS because by now, users already know full-well that it’s old and no longer updated, not to mention even old defs still catch old viruses. ◔_◔

Comment: @Synetech While the linked source is geared towards Forefront Endpoint Protection (FPE) and System Center Endpoint Protection (SCPE), Microsoft Security Essentials represents the consumer-oriented solution which share the same engine. In fact, the registry key is there after upgrading to version `4.5.216.0`, and I honestly doubt they would make an exception just for those people running MSE on Windows XP after July 2015. It's probably part of the FUD campaign against their soon-to-be-unsupported OS.

Comment: In case the above downloads are not available any more, here is a "modified MD4 checksum": D8BBEA56F33B165909BBF83E8C0B2F7C

Comment: I followed the instructions in the Workaround from "and31415" and found that the MSE "green house" icon does not appear in the System Tray until I restart "msseces2.exe", by using Process Explorer from SysInternals. Only then does the icon appear in the System Tray. I have rebooted the PC three more times, and each time I need to restart "msseces2.exe" to get the "green house" icon displayed in the System Tray.

Comment: @AlbertSteptoe I can't reproduce the issue. Which client/engine version are you currently using?

Comment: @Synetech An update on the end-of-life status: the anti-malware service appears to be programmed to stop one month before the actual deadline - June 15, 2015 to be precise. I don't know if this is by design or not, but it wouldn't make sense to provide further signature updates when the real-time protection is off anyway.

Comment: @and31415, that’s my point; even without new definitions, the real-time protection can still help defend against *existing* threats. Not all threats are new, current ones can come up at any time, so turning it off altogether is absurd. I guess their “reasoning” is that they figure by turning it off, they force the user to get another product and/or upgrade to Windows 8.1, but of course, neither of those is likely to be true in most cases.

Comment: They may as well disable GPO and passwords, and when they are ready to discontinue Vista, turn off UAC…

Comment: 7-Zip is unable to extract `epp.msi`. Tried WinRAR as well. Any tips? **EDIT:** Never mind, WinRAR was able to read the archive and extract the EXE file **alone** eventhough it kept saying the archive is corrupt. The checksum of extracted EXE file matched. Probably this is possible in 7-Zip GUI as well - I couldn't test as I was only using the CLI version.

Comment: @ADTC As of version `9.20`, 7-Zip is able to read and extract the cabinet archive embedded in `epp.msi`, both through the GUI and the CLI version (`7z.exe`); the *standalone* CLI version (`7za.exe`) won't, for some reason. Another way to extract the files is to use the Windows Installer command-line utility, e.g. `msiexec /a "X:\Path\to\epp.msi" /quiet targetdir="%temp%\epp"`

Comment: @and31415 , Thank you for a beautiful workaround:)

But today I noticed MSE started detecting this change as malware action. By removing it and rebooting, MSE gets red again. "Threat's" description:
http://www.microsoft.com/security/portal/threat/encyclopedia/entry.aspx?name=Behavior%3aWin32%2fMpTamperImgDeb.A&threatid=2147685200

So I turned off the automatics in MSE and added the "threat" to whitelist. After comparing registry dumps I think now we need to import this too:

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft Antimalware\Threats\ThreatIDDefaultAction]
"2147685200"=dword:00000006

Comment: PS: This key has no write permissions so it needs additional love:)

PPS: the DWORD value data=6 means "Ignore". Check "Overrides tab" here:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb418783.aspx

Comment: @saulius2 Thanks for the info; I was able to reproduce the issue myself, too. I didn't find your proposed solution to be optimal, so I took a different path. See my updated answer.

Comment: you genius: easy and complete solution. Thanks

Comment: It's now at stage 3 (unless some malware has effectively set my clock forward for this), and a new stage needs a new workaround. (the service starts and then stops - just replacing the GUI program is no longer effective)

Answer (score 3):

Funny enough, Microsoft pushes the new SE-version (4.5.216, with nagging screen) through automatic updates, but still has the previous version (4.4.304) available for manual download. I would not be surprised if they've pushed the 4.5-version only to XP-users.

Anyway, the solution is:

1. Manually download [Security Essentials here](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=231274). Keep it for later use.
2. Go to your configuration screen.
3. Select 'software' and uninstall Security Essentials.
4. Select 'Automatic updates' and opt for the second possibility (download and ask to install).
5. Install your downloaded version of Security Essentials.
6. The first time Windows Update asks you to update SE, you say no and click that you do not want to be bothered again about this update.

Comment: Use one of the links provided by **and31415**, whose solution is also better and smarter as it avoids Windows Update from offering or installing the newer version, or overwriting the EXE file.

Comment: i didnt get anything whats written. what is confg screen and software button or what? What Windows update has to do with SE updates? SE seperatly asks to update and it has its own Update button witch updates itself.

Answer (score 0):

To remove an update go to Control panel. Under add and remove programs click show all windows updates. Then find your update and uninstall it. If that does not work try system restore.

Comment: Are you saying that Windows' Error Reporting feature has something to do with this message displayed by Security Essentials?

Comment: Ok based on the image uploaded. Disabling error reporting service will not help.

Comment: I posted an image of the notification area and the small message window with the notification. There is no entry in the Applications tab in Task Manager with the title of the notification ("Microsoft Security Essentials").

Comment: It still looks like error is running under Microsoft Security Essentials or Services. The error is not generated from default error reporting service.